If a professor wants to hire a student themselves, how can they write a letter of recommendation for other universities?
Professors often write letters of recommendation for very promising undergrads for entry into PhD programs. Often these professors are interested in hiring these undergrads themselves. In fact one of the strongest statements a professor can say in such letters is "I would hire this student myself" or "I am planning to make an offer to this student" or some such statement.
This however seems to be a conflict of interest, as an unethical professor may deliberately write a lukewarm letter to reduce the candidate's chances of entry into other universities, and then offer admission to his own university. And there is no way the candidate can know that this happened.
How do professors manage these personal conflicts of interest?

I'm not sure what there is to "manage" here. The right course of action is obvious.

Are you asking from the student's or professor's perspective? It seems you write from the professor's, but please clarify for a good response.

How do professors manage these personal conflicts of interest? - By being professional.

Related: Why should a P.I be motivated to write a strong LOR even if that means losing a undergraduate from his/her lab?, Professor refusing to write recommendation letter to make student work longer

What do you mean "hire" the student?

Trying to coerce someone to stay, for employment or academia, at a place where they do not want to stay, is never a wise plan.  Even if you succeed, the employee will be disgruntled and unmotivated, never reaching full potential.  I struggle to see any professor or employer (except a very foolish one) seeing a benefit to trying.

"Often these professors are interested in hiring these undergrads themselves" Do you mean as a PhD student (PhD student's aren't "hired" in the US, but I understand they are elsewhere), or as an employee?

Perhaps it would make the letter stronger if the writer says "I would be happy to hire him here!"

@Laurel Is the new title asking for unethical tips?

@Anyon No? And even if someone did come to the question searching for that, the body of the question is very clear with what it's asking.

A good share of the world's functioning relies on people doing the right thing and behaving ethically. This is as true for the US presidency as it is for professors writing fair letters. Historically, most office holders do the right thing, and that's why things work as they do. Some, of course, don't and then things come apart a bit and we all hope that the consequences are limited.
In other words, we expect and hope for people to behave ethically because, if they don't, it is not always practically possible to put in place systems that oversee how everyone behaves -- because, if you had to create such systems for everything, you'd have more overseers than people doing the actual work.

And you'd also need overseers of overseers to make sure the overseers behave ethically...

@AlexanderWoo Precisely.

https://xkcd.com/2650/ "People lying" is a very old problem.  It's a known exploit.

Haha, can we get a citation for office holders like US presidents historically doing the right thing?

@walkar One can of course have differences in opinion about the policies of past presidents, but I think it is not unreasonable to claim that most of them have generally put the well-being of the country over personal gain.

@WolfgangBangerth I agree, I was just being pithy.

@walkar Another known bug in humanity 0.01.

For most professors there is no conflict of interests.
According to Joy's law "no matter who you are, most of the smartest people work for someone else.” At some stage of most professors' career, they learned this. Good people come, good people go, other good people come, and so on. It is not worth the trouble to try forcing people to stay if they have better prospect elsewhere.

I have had an applicant with a very strong cover letter from another potential advisor. The student eventually accepted an offer from that advisor.
Now, had the letter been lukewarm, the student would never have known, since it is confidential. But I would have seen where the student ended up, and would have known that the advisor was unethically putting their own interests ahead of the student's when writing the letter (being in a position where they would not take students they were genuinely lukewarm about). As a consequence, I would have avoided recommending them as a potential advisor to future students, since anyone who doesn't put the student's interests first would not be a good choice. I would also have been less likely to collaborate with them subsequently.
As it was, I know that this person behaved ethically, which might make me more likely to do these things. (In this particular case, however, it was someone I already knew to be ethical.)

For me, I don't think it is a conflict of interest. Let say students are all rational, so they are seeking a position in a better university compared with the current one.
Then if most members in a group can go to a better university, this can help attracting high quality applicant to join the lab in future.

As Wolfgang said, a lot of the world's functioning depends on people doing the right thing. But there is a selfish incentive if you think long term enough.
If they are a good student, then keeping them as a long term collaborator could be more valuable then trying to force them to stay with you. For one thing, if you are known as giving good reference letters and having impact with potential advisors, then that can (slightly) increase your pool of recruits. Anyone you harmed this way may meeting the person they applied to and find out about it, damaging long term relations.
If the work is similar enough, you may be able to collaborate with the student (though this is more valid for PhD student -> postdoc than undergrad -> PhD). Or they can be your advocator in this new group, again increasing your pool of potential recruits and recognition. And you can always keep them in mind as a good candidate for a future postdoc or faculty position (though faculty again is more for the PhD -> postdoc stage).
The other thing to keep in mind is that there is often an overabundance of students looking for the next step in academia. There are a lot more undergrads than PhDs, a lot more PhDs than postdocs, a lot more postdocs than faculty positions. So that suppresses the value of getting this one particular student, there may be similar options around.
If they are one of those special creme de la creme students, then they have a high chance of being able to demonstrate their ability outside of your report. Either through prior achievements(papers/talks/ect), personal impact they had on who they are applying to, or through their other references. This raises the chance of discovery while still having uncertainty on the chances of recruiting the student.
